# Define host and path frontend rule for Traefik

Tags: traefik

I am trying to use Traefik to deploy proxy multiple applications in my Docker Swarm mode cluster.

I have got it so that it proxies a named Host but I want  it to proxy on a named Host and Path, but I cannot work out the labels I need to use.

This is the `docker service` command I am using:

```
 docker service create \
                       \
    --label "traefik.port=9000" \
    --label "traefik.docker.network=traefik-net" \
    --label "traefik.frontend.rule=Host:`hostname -f`" \
    --label="traefik.backend=portainer" \
                                        \
    --constraint "node.role == manager" \
    -p 9000:9000 \
    --mount "type=bind,src=/var/run/docker.sock,dst=/var/run/docker.sock" \
    --name portainer \
    portainer/portainer
```

If the host is `dummy.localhost` then I am able to hit the portainer app on `http://dummy.localhost`.  However I want to modify it so that I have to use `http://dummy.localhost/portainer`.

I have seen that there are ways to do this when using a toml file for Traefik, but I am using watch mode and labels on the docker services I deploy.

How can I combine multiple front end rules in my labels so that this (and any other) application can be proxied on a hostname and a path?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

#### Traefik v1

If you want multiple rules to apply in order for a routing decision to become effective, separate them by semicolon. For instance:

```
Host: <your host rule>; PathPrefixStrip: /portainer
```

What the above means is: If the host and path prefix match, Traefik will route requests to the associated backend(s) (and strip off the specified path prefix prior to forwarding). This even works when defined inside a label.

See [the frontend documentation](https://docs.traefik.io/basics/#frontends) for details.

#### Update: Traefik v2

```
Host(`domain.com`) && Path(`/path`)
```

See [the docs](https://docs.traefik.io/v2.2/routing/routers/#rule)

Comment: Perfect thank you very much.  I was using a ',' instead of a ';' to setup multiple rules

Answer (score 1):

**Update: Traefik v2**

If  the path does not work

```
Host(`domain.com`) && Path(`/path`)
```

does not work, use PathPrefix

```
Host(`domain.com`) && Pathprefix(`/path`)
```

[Ref](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/v2.2/reference/dynamic-configuration/kubernetes-crd)