# Host and Path with Traefik V2

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, traefik

In reference to: [Define host and path frontend rule for Traefik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44232354/define-host-and-path-frontend-rule-for-traefik) (I wanted to comment on the answer but I can't)

I implemented the suggestion in the answer using

```
Host(`domain.com`) && Path(`/path`)
```

but it does not work (Getting 404 when trying to access it).

Traefik logs show:

> time="2020-07-07T10:31:30Z" level=error msg="field not found, node: rule " providerName=docker

My docker compose looks like this:

```
deploy:
  labels:
    - "traefik.enable=true"
    - "traefik.http.routers.typo3-${NAMEOFSERVICE}.rule = Host(`${HOSTNAME}`) && Path(`${DIRECTORY}`)"
```

When just using with the Host rule it works perfectly fine. But I want to be able to do e.g. `subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory` for service 1 and `subdomain.domain.com/subdirectory2` for service 2

I also tried `` - "traefik.http.routers.typo3-${NAMEOFSERVICE}.rule = Host(`${HOSTNAME}`) && PathPrefix(`${DIRECTORY}`)" `` but I get the same error in the log and 404.

Answer (score 1):

I found the Problem: remove the spaces around the "="

This works:

```
- "traefik.http.routers.typo3-${NAMEOFSERVICE}.rule=(Host(`${HOSTNAME}`) && Path(`${DIRECTORY}`))"
```

I now have another problem. My service in this subdirectory, redirects outside of it. (Example, Typo 3 first install: I access subdomain.domain.com/foo and it redirects me to subdomain.domain.com/typo3/install.php)